# Solving for a function inside a finite summation

Tags: summation

I trying to solve for a function inside a finite summation and haven't been able to find many resources on the topic.  Below is the general form of the equation and I'd like to rearrange it so solve for the function $f(n)$.  It seems like there should be some theorem about this form but I can't seem to find anything.  Thanks.

$$x=\sum_{n=1}^{N}g(n)f(n)$$

Comment: Is the equation you give  for a fixed $N$, or is it true for any $N$?

Comment: For the expression above, N would be a predetermined fixed value. It would not be true for any random N.

Comment: Is there anything specific you can say about $g(n)$?

Comment: $g(n)$ is a list of coefficients which gives a different coefficient for each $n$ and $f(n)$ is an analytic function that is also a function of $n$.  This is essentially the summation of coefficients multiplied by an analytic function.

Comment: For a fixed $N$ and $g(n)$ there are infinite possibilities for $f(n)$.  It is underdetermined.